# shared_ptr<void> t(new char[num]) means memory leak?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, shared-ptr, tr1

```
shared_ptr<void> t(new char[num])
```

means memory leak?

If so, what is the correct practice in this case.

should I use shared_array<> instead?

I'm editing the bytes pointed by 't' manually for later transfer in a TCP Stream.

Comment: A correct practice is not to use `void` as shared_ptr's template type.

Comment: Why would that cause a memory leak in any case?  `shared_ptr` works on array types doesn't it?  `unique_ptr` does.

Comment: @VJo: Thanks, but the reason I'm using a void* is because I'm allocating 'num' bytes for storage of different types of variables, like the first 4 bytes represent a double, next 2 bytes are short.

Comment: Calling delete on a pointer-to-void results in undefined behavior.  Don't do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293326/deleting-pointer-sometimes-results-in-heap-corruption/1708737#1708737

Comment: Note that this will call `operator delete`, not `operator delete[]`, which is twice undefined (pointer-to-void, and not an array). This will _possibly_ work just fine, but it may _quite possibly_ crash, or leak, or do any other possible thing.

Comment: @VJo, Damon's point is that on another compiler it might appear to work. Never try to pin down the exact consequence of UB because it's pointless.

Comment: what if I type char instead of void & replace shared_ptr with shared_array so delete[] is called?

Comment: There's an awful lot of misinformation about `shared_ptr<void>` in these answers... which I'm guessing is why http://stackoverflow.com/q/7881003/293791 popped up.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose - Thanks! I was obviously parroting what I read, without thinking for myself. Hopefully my answer is beter now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> means memory leak?

No, it means undefined behavior. (Which could have any symptom, including memory leak.) The call to `delete` must match the call to `new`. Yours doesn't. You allocate with `new[]` but destroy with `delete`.

> If so, what is the correct practice in this case. Should I use shared_array<> instead?

There are two easy choices. You can use `shared_array`:

```
shared_array<char> t(new char[num])
t[7] = 42;
```

Or, you could use a `shared_ptr` to a `std::vector`:

```
shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > t(new std::vector<char>(num))
(*t)[7] = 42;
```

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Dennis Zickefoose for gently pointing out an error in my thinking. Parts of my answer are rewritten.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm not equipped with a Profile/Analyze utility ATM, so I have no way to verify it, but I'm counting on it for now.

Answer (score 3):

As I see the `void` You mention in the Q is a typo, Since Calling delete on a `void *` is guaranteed Undefined Behavior by the Standard.

For another data type,

You will have to provide your custom `deletor` to the `shared_ptr` so you can call `delete []`.

Eg:

For example:

```
template<typename T>
struct Customdeleter
{
   void operator()(T* p)
   {
      delete [] p;
   }
};
```

And invoke as:

```
shared_ptr<char> sp(new char[num], Customdeleter<char>());
```

EDIT:
Since you clarified are using Boost in comments and not TR1(AFAIK TR1 doesn't have shared_array)

You can use `shared_array`:

```
shared_array<char> sp(new char[num])
```

Comment: Still undefined behavior to call delete[] on void*

Comment: A custom deleter is an option, but i prefer to avoid using these, is there another way? what if i type char instead of void & replace shared_ptr with shared_array so delete[] is called?

Comment: @AlonAmir: AFAIK, TR1 does not have a shared_array.So Custom deleter is the way to go about it.

Comment: I'm using boost because I'm cross compiling over iOS and the NDK on adnroid

Comment: @AlonAmir: Then yes you should use shared_array. Sorry I was confused by the TR1 tag in the Question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see where you're coming from - you want `void *` pointers so you can later cast it to the final type you're serializing. But as others have pointed out, you can't delete a `void*` pointer, and neither can the code for `shared_ptr`.

Since you're allocating an array of char, that should be the type of smart pointer you use:

```
shared_array<char> t(new char[num]);
```

Casting the raw char pointer to another type shouldn't be any more of a problem than casting a `void*` pointer.

Comment: It will call delete, not delete[]

Comment: @Pubby8, that's why I suggested `shared_array`.

Comment: exactly. 1+ for the extra hint.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `delete` on `void*` which is undefined behavior.

> the reason I'm using a void* is because I'm allocating 'num' bytes for storage of different types of variables, like the first 4 bytes represent a double, next 2 bytes are short..

Use a struct or union then.

Comment: This should probably be merged to a comment.

Comment: Using shared_ptr<void> is not undefined behavior - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881003/why-is-shared-ptrvoid-not-specialized - it's use is also encouraged - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#pvoid

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if C++11 has a shared_array, [but Boost does](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) — you should use that instead.